# How do I setup Fiddler to advertise it as real server under test?

Tags: networking, proxy, proxy-server, fiddler

I have one client and 3 servers running. Suppose the client is running on

```
http://localhost:8000
```

and the other three servers are running at:

```
http://localhost:8001    ----->server1

http://localhost:8002    ------->server2

http://localhost:8003    --------->server3
```

There also is communication between these servers. My question is:

1. Can Fiddler be placed "in front of" the server2 by advertising its IP instead of the actual server2? If yes, then how?
2. When Fiddler receives a POST request from a client, I want to modify the message and then forward it to server2? How can this be achieved?
3. Similarly, when the response comes back from the server2, modify it as needed before returning it to the client.

If the above operations can not be done by Fiddler proxy server, please suggest me another proxy server which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

While its not Fiddler's standard use-case, it can be configured as a reverse proxy.  The detailed instructions can be found in the [Fiddler Documentaton](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy), but basically:

1. Configure Fiddler to accept remote connections
2. Set the port number for the destination server (`8002` for `server2`) using a DWORD value named `ReverseProxyForPort` in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2`, then restart Fiddler.
3. Write a FiddlerScript `OnBeforeRequest` rule to re-write the `Host` header for incoming requests:

Script:

```
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "fiddlerserver:8888") oSession.host = "server2:8002";
```

I would also configure Fiddler so that it doesn't automatically proxy all requests on the machine via the "Act as system proxy on startup" checkbox under the "Connections" tab in the settings.

You can further modify any POST request using additional FiddlerScript rules.